# plugings request url is the old url

Tags: plugins, content, wp-config

I have changed my WordPress site url in wp-config.php by adding this two lines:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http:// $new url' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http:// $new url' );
```

almost everything working fine, but I have some plugins that still trying to get data from the old url, for example:

```
https://OLD URL/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/eicons/fonts/eicons.woff?5.3.0
```

there is another place that I should update the new url for the plugins?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that should be enough.

- Elementor sets its base URL `ELEMENTOR_URL` from [`plugins_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)
- `plugins_url` uses WP_PLUGIN_URL which is set in default-constants.php
- WP_PLUGIN_URL is constructed from WP_CONTENT_URL which is constructed from `get_option('siteurl')`
- there's a default `options_siteurl` filter called `_config_wp_siteurl` that overrides the value fetched from the database with WP_SITEURL if set.

So assuming you don't have WP_PLUGIN_URL defined and that this isn't a multisite, there's nothing else you need to configure, no. I'd start by checking the value of WP_PLUGIN_URL that's being generated by default-constants.php, or if you have any `plugins_url` filters defined somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where plugins_url can be?

Comment: A plugins_url filter? In any other plugin, or in your theme. But that does seems a bit unlikely to me. It's probably worth tracing out all the values of ELEMENTOR_URL, WP_PLUGIN_URL and WP_CONTENT_URL to try and see where the old path is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Please try going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking the "Save Changes" button.
This will flush the rewrite rules. You don't need to make any changes and it will still work.

You can also do it with the `flush_rewrite_rules();` function. But, you wouldn't want to leave it in your code since you only need to flush the rewrite rules once.

If that doesn't work there are more things to try.

**Edit**

Take a backup of your site before continuing, and save it remotely (not on the same server as the site)!

The next thing I would do is search the database and see if I can find the old URL stored there. Then, you can find where it needs to be changed (and diagnose any issues thenceforth).
Additionally, since the issue you posted above is related to Elementor, you may want to try running Elementor's Search and Replace tool as described [here](https://elementorresources.com/tutorials/search-and-replace-urls-using-elementor/). If you prefer to use something other than Elementor's tool (I have never used it personally) you can try [this](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), which I have found to make reliable work of the task.

If the old URL is not in your database, it must be hard-coded somewhere.
If that is the case, let me know and I can describe how to run `grep` on your code base to find where the string is hiding.

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks :), but it didnt work, do you have another idea?

Comment: Updated the answer, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here, but according to Elementor doc. it must have `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` set equal.

> Sometimes, if your URL in the back-end is different than the one in the front-end it can also lead to this problem. Make sure that the Site Address (URL) is the same as the WordPress Address (URL) to avoid loading issues.

*source: https://elementor.com/help/cant-edit-with-elementor/*

with that in mind, some settings/text is stored in the database, including the previous domain name.

So also go through the data in the database and change the old domain name to the new one. (remember to backup first!)

Comment: They are equal in the question, aren't they?